# swift change behavior of nspopover

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, popover

i show a popover from my view controller like this way:

```
let vcPopover = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "vcPopover") as! vcPopover
self.presentViewController(vcKundePopover, asPopoverRelativeTo : sender.bounds, of : sender, preferredEdge: .maxX, behavior: .transient)
```

this works fine.
is it possible to change the behavior of the nspopover directly from the showed popover with a button?

i mean: i open the popover with the code above.
in this this popover should be a button. if i pressed the button, the view can only close with another button (behavior semi-transient). if i pressed the button again the behavior should change to transient and you can close the popover with a click outside of the popover.

Comment: It's a settable field.  Are you saying that setting it does not work?

Comment: no, i am searching for a solution, which can change the behavior of a popover which is actual showing

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.  Have you tried setting it?  Does it or does it not work for you?